# Background color vanishes on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I built a table using html/css. The background colors for this table appear just fine on a desktop environment but not when I look at the same site from my phone.

On the phone the background colors to this table are completely transparent, but the text in the table appears just fine.

Also, I am using Bootstrap 4 for this site if that makes any difference. I thought it may be css interfering with the bootstrap css for some reason, but this problem still occurs even when using the !important;

CSS:

```
#beatsTable tr {
    background-color:rgb(123, 126, 132, 1) !important;
    padding:10px;
    padding:10px;
}

#beatsTable tr:not(:nth-child(2)):hover {
    background-color:rgb(55, 56, 58, 0.5);
}

#beatsTable td {
    color:gray;
    padding:10px;
    color:white;
}

#beatsTable th {
    padding:10px;
    background-color:rgb(17, 17, 17, 0.5);
    border-bottom:1px solid rgb(46, 204, 57, 0.5);
    border-top:1px solid rgb(46, 204, 57, 0.5);
    font-size:15px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- <center><img src="media/beatLab.png"></img></center> -->

  <table style="color:white" id="beatsTable">
  <tr>
    <div class="musicPlayerContainer">

    </div>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Time</th> 
    <th>Bpm</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name1</td>
    <td>3:12</td> 
    <td>120</td>
    <td><div class="buyBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#purchaseModal">Buy</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name2</td>
    <td>4:20</td> 
    <td>153</td>
    <td><div class="buyBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#purchaseModal">Buy</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name3</td>
    <td>6:09</td> 
    <td>100</td>
    <td><div class="buyBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#purchaseModal">Buy</div></td>
  </tr>
  </table>


</div>
```

Picture of table on desktop: http://prntscr.com/jtud8h

Picture of table on mobile: http://prntscr.com/jtudjt

Comment: Did you forget to clear your phone cache?

Comment: @PHPglue Good thought. I have tried that. I have also been testing it in an incognito window.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated by FYI you're trying to give the background an alpha value of `1` or `0.5` but in order for it to take effect you must use `rgba` instead of `rgb`

Comment: @Andrew That fixed it. Thank you! If you create an answer I will upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might have something to do with the fact that you're trying to give the background an alpha value of `1` or `0.5` but in order for it to take effect you must use `rgba` instead of `rgb`

Hope that helped!